# Can't edit DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, windows

I have a `DataGridVeiw` and was able to edit the rows without any issues and as soon as I start to edit, it was adding a new row. All of sudden the grid has become non-editable and not adding any row. I don't remember, I have changed any settings. I am not sure what and where I went wrong, I have one more `DataGridView` in another tab, which is working absolute fine.

Comment: Post the code of your gridview

Comment: Have you compared the property settings of both the grids?

Comment: Without code it is hard to help.

Comment: I figured the problem. The issue was I created "edit control showing" event, I has to remove this, Instead of column name, I used COLUMN1, column2 and it worked. //TextBox SSN;
            //if (e.Control is TextBox)
            //{
            //    SSN = e.Control as TextBox;
            //    SSN.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(SSN_KeyPress);
            //}  private void SSN_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }